# What is the best way to block specific URL for testing?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, web-scraping, fiddler

I am observing a website with Google Chrome and Fiddler version 4.4.

The page is using AJAX to update its data. I want to block a specific URL to test what will happen if it doesn't work.

What is the easiest way to block the URL?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What would you like to have happen?

Go to the AutoResponder tab. Tick **Enable Automatic Responses** and **Unmatched requests pass through**. Click the **Add** button. In the top box, enter **http://example.com/yourURLisHere**. In the box below it, select either **404_Plain.dat** or choose ***drop** or ***reset**. The first returns a 404. The second just drops the connection if it sees the target URL. The third sends a TCP/IP RST packet if it sees the target URL.

Comment: thanks @ericlaw. its Perfect. and how I could hide it from session list? actually I used **302_Redirect.dat** and check **Hide Redirects** in Filters tab. is there any other way that I missed?

Comment: To hide the request from the session list, you'd probably want to create another rule for the same URL, with the ActionText set to *flag:ui-hide=1 and make sure that this rule appears EARLIER in the list than the one that returns the response.

Comment: Is there a way to block requests containing a specific text in it?

Comment: @bells: If you think that's a different question than the question above, then please ask a new question on StackOverflow (and explain) rather than making a comment.